# Ubuntu 14.04 Apache 2.4.7 manage multiple php versions

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I'm following this tutorial to run multiple php versions

https://blogs.ashrithgn.com/2019/01/02/serving-multiple-version-php-ubuntu-14-16-18-04-lts/

I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS with apache 2.4.7

The tutorial indicates to write this code on mysite.conf

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

After some research I found out that to run .sock files I need apache 2.4.10+

After more research I found that I should use ProxyPassMatch but I don't know how and can't find a way to make it work.

Any help ?

Here is an answer but it does not explain how to make it work

[Sethandler fcgi proxy not working on Ubuntu 14.04/Apache 2.4.7 php7.2-fpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395752/sethandler-fcgi-proxy-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-apache-2-4-7-php7-2-fpm/57275021#57275021)

Doing this does not work:

```
sudo nano mysite.conf
```

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
```

It shows this error:
ProxyPass URL must be absolute!

I guess because I should remove unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock